# Programmatic WCF based access to SQL Server Reporting Services 2010 web services

Tags: wcf, api, reporting-services, soapheader

Previously we have developed against the ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx web service.

To access these web services, the MSDN documentation suggests the old .NET 2.0 based web service reference technologies. But we specifically chose to use the WCF (System.ServiceModel) technology to access this service. Regardless of whether you use .NET 2.0 WSDL or WCF Service References, in both cases proxy classes are generated to wrap the web service methods. Noteworthy, the proxy classes themselves will have different (but functionally equal) implementations. *Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155134.aspx*

We have had great success with the WCF based service proxy against the ReportService2005 (for SSRS 2008). Recently, we were asked to do the same but to use the new ReportService2010 web service (for SQL Server 2008 R2) as the old ReportService2005.asmx/ReportService2006.asmx services have been deprecated. *Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154052.aspx*

*For context: The ReportService2006.asmx services are intended for using SSRS in a Sharepoint Integrated mode - presumably this has mostly to do with security (authentication/authorisation).*

In the most simplest terms the new ReportService2010.asmx services are an almalgamation of the old ReportService2005.asmx and ReportService2006.asmx services, and you are now able to use the ReportService2010.asmx services for either "Native" or "SharePoint Integrated" scanarios.

After all that, my question is what else is different at an API level? 
PS: I also found that SSRS2008R2 no longer supports `Anonymous` usage
For example I noticed that in the old services used to specify that the WCF Client security mode was set for "TransportCredentialOnly" using NTLM and passing your Username from the ClientCredentials. In contrast, the new 2010 services has the WCF Client security mode now set to "None" and the message still contains the UserName, but without any transport security (like NTLM).

OK, so I'm starting to guess that the act of integrating the 2005/2006 services (which likely used different authentication mechanisms) results in this change we see.

This though, has a direct impact on the API code in that previously you would be specifying the credential for the Client proxy as follows:

```
proxy.ClientCredentials.ClientCredential = yourCredential;
```

This no longer seems relevant. I also noticed that many of the proxy service methods now expect a `TrustedUserHeader` instance as the first parameter. For example:

```
proxy.CreateFolder( yourTrustedUserHeader, folder , ... );
```

From some documentation it appears to be implemented as a SOAP Header. This TrustedUserHeader object contains properties like `UserName`, `UserToken`, `AnyAttr`, etc. but I'm not sure what the proper usage pattern is. Unfortunately the MSDN documentation is equally useless in that I could not find clear guidance on this issue, nor do the MSDN documentaion use WCF ServiceModel to access the services.

Can anyone please provide some insight as to the appropriate way to now use the new Reporting Services 2010 interface? 
Should I no longer set the "ClientCredentials" property, and instead create and instance of the "TrustedUserHeader"

Many thanks!
Jaans

Comment: It would appear from intial testing that the default generated WCF binding security for the ReportService2010.asmx WCF proxy is wrong in that I'm only able to establish a connection with the following in the app.config for the SOAP binding configuration: `<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">` and also setting the `<transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm" ... />`

Comment: Do you know what AuthenticationTypes are in your rsreportserver.config? <AuthenticationTypes><RSWindowsNegotiate/>
   <RSWindowsNTLM/>
  </AuthenticationTypes>